# they or he/she when the gender/count is not known?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Consider the following sentence. Which one is correct? Why?

- Someone called but as soon as *they* heard my voice they hung up.
- Someone called but as soon as *he/she* heard my voice they hung up.

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to a usage known  as the "singular they."

***[Singular they](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they):***

> - is the use in English of the pronoun they, or its inflected or derivative forms, such as them, their, themself, or themselves, as a gender-neutral pronoun to refer to a single person or an antecedent that is grammatically singular. It typically occurs with an antecedent of indeterminate gender, as in sentences such as:
>
>   - "Somebody left their umbrella in the office. Would they please collect it?"
>   - *"The patient should be told at the outset how much they will be required to pay."*
>   - *"But a journalist should not be forced to reveal their sources."*
> - The singular they had emerged by the 14th century and is common in everyday spoken English, but its use has been the target of criticism since the late 19th century. ***Its use in formal English has increased with the trend toward gender-inclusive language.***

Comment: -1 for an answer that consists almost entirely of a quote of an outside source  See this [ELL meta question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1344/are-answers-which-consist-only-of-block-quotes-acceptable?noredirect=1&lq=1) for  justification of my downvote